# Como gerar e baixar um excel de um grande volume de dados em ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, mvc

Olá eu tenho aplicação Web que disponibiliza um download de conteúdo da base de dados em formato excel, estou utilizando no meu controller um método do tipo FileResult. Abaixo versão resumida do código.

Simples link de download

```
                    <div>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadExcel","DeliveryReport")">Download Excel</a>
                </div>
```

Função do controller

```
        public FileResult DownloadExcel(DeliveryReportViewModel model)
        {
           var dto = Service.GetDto();
           byte[] filecontent = ConverToExcel(dto);
           return File(filecontent, ExcelExportHelper.ExcelContentType, 
           ExcelExportHelper.GenerateFileName(Resources.DeliveryReport));
        }
```

Funciona perfeitamente até certa quantidade de registros, o problema é quando há um grande volume de dados. O tempo de requisição não dura mais que um minuto então quando ultrapassa esse tempo de espera me é devolvido um erro mesmo com o controller dando continuidade ao processo dos dados. De que forma eu poderia deixar a requisição durando o tempo que fosse necessário até o download do arquivo? Ou quem sabe deixando esse processo em segundo plano enquanto o usuário continua a usar o sistema?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar o fluxo de forma que na rota o usurário solicita o a geração do arquivo e ao terminar você encaminha um e-mail para o mesmo com um link para baixa o arquivo.